# Print out only the first column in a non-standard CSV file

Tags: csv, awk

I have a file that is delimited by comma ",", but some rows have only one column, and some rows have multiple columns separated by ",". For example:

```
NM_001066
NM_015378,NM_018156
NM_001006624,NM_001006625,NM_006474,NM_198389
```

As you can see above, the third line has 4 columns delimited by ",", but I only need to get the first column in every line.

I tried to use awk: `cat fileName.txt | awk '{print $1}'`, but it does not work. I am looking for help with this. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you're looking for this:

```
awk -F, '{print $1}' file.txt
```

`-F,` tells `awk` to use comma as the field separator.

In this simple case, the same thing is simpler with `cut`:

```
cut -f1 -d, file.txt
```

Comment: thanks, so "-d," tells cut to use comma "," as the delimiter, right? appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

you are close:

```
awk -F, '{print $1}' file
```

or

```
awk -F, '$0=$1' file
```